# How to get line breaks in a callback function (%s or .format)

Tags: python, callback, string-formatting, plotly-dash

I am working on a Dash web-application where the idea is to be able to predict an outcome based on a selected model and some values that are given as input via a daq-slider.

The selection of the model (from a dropdown menu) and the return of a prediction (return which model that has been selected, the predicted class (yes/no), as well as the percentage probability of yes and no) works well. My issue is that I want the returned outcome to be separated by line-breaks - but it returns the result as one long paragraph.

The callback, that looks like this (a simplified version + did not include code for the slider and dropdown menu):

```
@callback(Output('slider-container', 'children'),
         [Input('model-dropdown', 'value'), 
          Input('v1', 'value'), 
          Input('v2', 'value')]

def predict_function(m, v1, v2):
    model = models[m]
    X_new = np.array([v1, v2])
    y_pred = model.predict(X_new)
    y_proba = model.predict_proba(X_new)*100
    df_proba = pd.DataFrame({'Yes': y_proba[:, 0], 'No': y_proba[:, 1]})
    yes = np.round(pd_proba.iloc[0]['Yes'], decimals=5)
    no = np.round(pd_proba.iloc[0]['No'], decimals=5)
    for i in range(len(X_new)):
        return "Model: %s \n" \
               "Prediction: %s \n" \
               "Probability for Yes: %s \n" \
               "Probability for No: %s \n" \ 
               %(m, y_pred[i], yes, no)
```

Results in something like this (in the dash web-application):

```
Model: <m> Prediction: <y_pred> Probability for Yes: <yes> Probability for No: <no>
```

Instead of the wanted outcome:

```
Model: <m> 
Prediction: <y_pred> 
Probability for Yes: <yes> 
Probability for No: <no>
```

I have tried to reproduce the issue, using a simple example. Here it returns \n in the outcome (it does not return \n in the Dash app - there it just ignores the \n as it wasn't there). I have tried both with %s and .format:

```
def calc_x(x):
    y = x+2
    z = y+5
    return "X: %s \n Y: %s \n Z: %s" % (x, y, z)

calc_x(5)
# 'X: 5 \n Y: 7 \n Z: 12'

def calc_x(x):
    y = x+2
    z = y+5
    return ('X: {} \n Y: {} \n Z: {}').format(x, y, z)
# 'X: 5 \n Y: 7 \n Z: 12'

calc_x(5)


def calc_x(x):
    y = x+2
    z = y+5
    return ('X: {}\nY: {}\nZ: {}').format(x, y, z)

calc_x(5)
# 'X: 5\nY: 7\nZ: 12'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Try using `html.Br()`

Comment: `HTML` needs `<br>` instead of `\n` to display it as new line. OR you have to put text in `<pre>Text</pre>` to display new line with `\n` - but it uses monospace font to display it - like code in your question.

Comment: Try changing the "return" to "print" (and don't forget the parenthesis)

Comment: The html.Br() in the return statement resulted in a Synthax error when placed outside the quotes. Inside the quotes it simply prints html.Br() as a part of the app output.

Comment: Replacing \n with <br> results in that <br> is being printed as a part of the app output (\n is not printed as a part of the output - nor does it result in the wanted linebreaks). The same happens when using the <pre>Text</pre> suggestion (it is getting printed as a part of the output).

Comment: For the print instead of return suggestion, it correctly inserts the wanted line breaks - but it prints the output in the terminal instead of in the app (leaving a blank text field in the app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your return statement

```
return (html.P(["Model:{}".format(m),html.Br(),"Prediction:{}".format(y_pred[i]),html.Br(),"Probability for Yes:{}".format(yes),html.Br(),"Probability for No:{}".format(no)]))
```

Hope this works.